# Fail in rviz ros fuerte

Tags: rviz, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my name is Zaid Issa
I installed ros fuerte, but I had these errores when I launched roscore and rviz
--------------rviz-----------------

> X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap
> or Window parameter) 9   Major opcode:
> 55 (X_CreateGC)   Resource id:
> 0x4c00004

------------------roscore------------------

> log4cxx: Could not read configuration
> file
> [/opt/ros/fuerte/ros/config/rosconsole.config].

Thank you
Be Coool

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32424/fail-in-rviz-ros-fuerte/) by [SD zaid issa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2233/sd-zaid-issa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#1 is likely a bug in QT 4.8.1, what version of QT is installed on your system?

#2 is not really a problem itself, but if you want it to go away, set $ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE to the path of an actual config file, explained here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole#Configuration

That being said, if $ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE is not set, it looks like you might be redefining $ROS_ROOT, which by default in fuerte is set to "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros" and not "/opt/ros/fuerte/ros".

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2